# Angular 2 errors in VS2017

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017

In VS2015 I didn't have any errors with Angular2. I've ported my code to VS2017 and now I get a total of 78 errors all have code TS2304 or TS2339 errors and they all relate to

> index.d.ts

Here's my tsconfig.json file:

```
{  
"compilerOptions": {
"noImplicitAny": true,
"noEmitOnError": true,
"removeComments": false,
"sourceMap": true,
"target": "es6",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"module": "commonjs",
"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true  },
"exclude": [
  "node_modules/*"
  ],
  "typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types/"
  ]
}
```

Also strangely enough, I have 6 projects that make up my solution. Only 1 project requires angular and typescript references as all other projects are .net core library projects for my service and repository layers. The errors are all against the other 5 projects (the ones that do not require the reference).

[image]

Comment: Which version of TypeScript are you running? VS2017 probably comes with a newer version than you were using before. Your errors are common when switching from an earlier version to TypeScript >2

Comment: @JohannaLarsson In my Nuget Installed packages I have : `Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler V2.2.1` and `Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild V2.2.2`

Comment: also in my package.json file I have a reference in my devDependencies section of `typescript: ^2.2.2`

Answer (score 0):

For fix, change the "target" value (**tsconfig.json**) to '`es2015`' or another value.

example:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    **"target": "es2015",**
    "module": "commonjs", 
    .......
   }
}
```

Comment: if I change it from `es6` to `es2015` I still receive the same error. If I change it to any of `es3`, `es5`, `esnext`, `es2016` or `es2017` I receive compile time errors